# Increased Records while reading tar file with JSON formatted Data

Tags: python, json, csv

20190528.tar.gz file has 144,390 files and 22,673,735 records. Each file has some thousands JSON formatted data.

**One Raw Record in single line [I've structured this to understand better]:**

```
{
    "t_id":"80740185.1558980000000.120184.121164",
    "s_id":"80740185",
    "pt_slot":"null:null",
    "ch_id":1,"o_id":121164,"c_id":120184,
    "msg_type":1,
    "amd":"{
                \"msg\":\" some Bengali text\",
                \"mask\":\"1GB_OFFER\",
                \"ec\":\"1\",
                \"time-out\":\"0\",
                \"validity\":\"30052019 000000\"
           }",
    "time":1558960217731,
    "dlr":"1",
    "msisdn":"xxxxx",
    "entity":1
}
```

I'm reading the tar.gz file and trying to make pipe separated CSV Files.

**Here Is My Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import csv
import ast
import tarfile

def write_sms_dat_to_csv_file():
        tar= tarfile.open('20190528.tar.gz','r:gz')
        csv_writer = csv.writer(open('csv_data.txt','wb+'),delimiter = '|')
        for member in tar.getmembers():
                f = tar.extractfile(member)
                if f is not None:
                        data = []
                        for line in f.readlines():
                                print(line.strip())
                                data.append(json.loads(line.strip()))
                                for dt in data:
                                        csv_writer.writerow([dt['c_id'],dt['msisdn'],ast.literal_eval(dt['amd'])['mask'],ast.literal_eval(dt['amd'])['ec']])

if __name__=="__main__":
        write_sms_dat_to_csv_file()
```

Above code has no issues, works fine. The problem is its creating the CSV file with more records than it should.  I mean much more records. Code is not finishing even the output records reached 30 million. I had to kill.

I mean output record number should be same as input record number.

I'm failing to find the bug in my code for which record is being duplicated.

Could you help to find the error in logic? Thanks.

Comment: Does each file in the tar have 22,673,735 records or is that the total amount of records across all 144,390 files?

Comment: Total amount of records is 22,673,735 across all 144,390 files. @Will

Comment: SO you'd except 22,673,735 rows in the CSV right?

Comment: That's right @Will

Comment: Got it. I'll post below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `data` list. It is keeping memory every time you read lines and then you loop over it again to do the csv write. Not too sure why you need `data` ...

Try this

```
if f is not None:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line.strip())
        dt = json.loads(line.strip())
        csv_writer.writerow([dt['c_id'], .....
```

Comment: It's Python, so it's called a list, not an array.

Comment: array was used in the generic non-coding sense as opposed to the python-data-structure-employed sense. But thank you @Barmar, that was super helpful.

Comment: I constantly have to fix my Python answers because I think "array" generically as well. In the Python context, arrays refers to numpy.

Comment: Actually, in Python arrays are a stand library data type. But then we're getting pedantic.

Comment: so silly mistake i made... csv_writer loop should be outside of that loop which appending data to data list. Thanks mate. @Will

Comment: @Leon yeah, only, that list is completely redundant and will just double your memory usage